# Liquid gathering at bottom of fresh natto

Tags: food-safety

Fifth batch. Threw out third batch because of liquid at bottom. Fourth was fine. Now, once again, liquid gathering at bottom.

Sterilized utensils, soaked beans for 12 hours, cooked at pressure for 30 minutes, incubated with store natto below 176°F, fermented at 1-1.5 inch depth in Instant Pot set to "Yogurt" for 24 hours.

Smells right, nice and stringy, except for liquid at bottom, looks fine.

Is liquid sign of something gone wrong?